# Removing a sublist from a list

Tags: python, list, sublist, remove-if

I have a list e.g. `l1 = [1,2,3,4]` and another list: `l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4]`. 
I would like to check if `l1` is a subset in `l2` and if it is, then I want to delete these elements from `l2` such that `l2` would become `[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]`, where indexes 0-3 have been removed.

Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

I tried this:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
l3 = []
for i in l2:
    if i in l1:
        l3.append(i)
-> prints [5,6,7]
```

However I would like the output to be `[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: `[i for i in l1+l2 if (i not in l1) or (i not in l2)]` I think this is all you need

Answer (score 3):

Well, here is a brute-force way. There are probably more efficient ways. If you expect to encounter a matching sublist early, the performance shouldn't be terrible.

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in range(0, len(l2), len(l1)):
...     if l2[i:len(l1)] == l1:
...         del l2[i:len(l1)]
...         break
...
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l2
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Or if you don't want to modify `l2`, you could do the following:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in range(0, len(l2), len(l1)):
...     if l2[i:len(l1)] == l1:
...         break
...
>>> l2[:i] + l2[i+len(l1):]
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proud of this, and it's not pythonic, but I thought it might be a bit of fun to write. I've annotated the code to make it a little more obvious what's happening.

```
>>> import re
>>> from ast import literal_eval

>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
>>> literal_eval(         # convert the string into a python collection
...    re.sub(            # use a regex as a replacement
...       str(l1)[1:-1],  # string of the list, without surrounding brackets
...       '',             # replace with empty
...       str(l2)[1:-1],  # string for replacement, again without brackets
...       count=1         # only replace the first match
...    ).strip(',')       # replace any preceeding or trailing commas
...     .strip()          # replace any preceeding or trailing whitespace
... )
(5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The output here is a tuple, but you could wrap it in `list()` if that's what you really want. Again, I'm not proud of this, but it works at least for this simple case. Juanpa's solution is much more preferable to this.