# Subtracting one list from another in python where duplicate values may occur

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, subtraction

I am looking to remove the contents of one array from another.

```
array_2 = ['one' , "two" , "one", "three", "four"]
array_1 = ['one', "two"]
```

My first thought was to use list [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
array_3 = [x for x in array_2 if x not in array_1]
```

However this will remove the duplicate item 
result : `['three', 'four']`

I want to only remove `"one"` once from the array as I am looking for a list subtraction. So I want the result to be : `['one', 'three', 'four']`.

What is a good pythonic way to achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: No the answers provided in that thread would remove all instances of 'one' I only want to delete an instance by instance as noted above

Comment: Yes they do. One the answers using `collections.Counter` does exactly that, which has already been repeated multiple times in the answers below. The answer: [stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists/42081195#42081195](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists/42081195#42081195).

Comment: apologies , that answer was buried deep in amongst the red herrings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python removing overlap of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717984/python-removing-overlap-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just going to collect the excellent solutions already given above.

If you care about maintaining the original order in which the elements in `array_2` were, then I think you have to use `remove`:

```
array_1 = ['one', 'two']
array_2 = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'four']
array_3 = list(array_2)
for x in array_1:
    try:
        array_3.remove(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(array_3)
```

If it does not matter what the final order of elements is, then using `Counter` is much more efficient as it only loops over both lists once:

```
from collections import Counter

array_1 = ['one', 'two']
array_2 = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'four']
array_3 = list((Counter(array_2) - Counter(array_1)).elements())
print(array_3)
```

Comment: for what it is worth I found that the answer from @Sparky05 proved to be the faster of the two on my dataset

Comment: @Steve Yes, for your example, using `remove` is faster, as initializing a `Counter` object can take a little while.
However, if you were using two lists that have sizes over, let's say, 10k, then using `Counter` is much, much faster.

Comment: @1313e Edit the code in the first block: `array_3 = list(array_2)` and `for x in array_1:`

Answer (score 5):

Try `Counter` from `collections`:

```
from collections import Counter

array_2 = ['one' , "two" , "one", "three", "four"]
array_1 = ['one', "two"]

list((Counter(array_2) - Counter(array_1)).elements())
```

**output**

```
['one', 'three', 'four']
```

Comment: This one probably works better than using `remove`, as it only requires to loop over both lists once. For big lists, that would make a big difference.
However, it does not actually maintain the order in which all elements in `array_2` were.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `remove` method of list:

```py
array_2 = ['one' , "two" , "one", "three", "four"]
array_1 = ['one', "two"]

# copy list
array_3 = array_2[:]

for element in array_1:
    try:
        array_3.remove(element)
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(array_3)
# ['one', 'three', 'four']
```

Comment: Thats actually how I went about solving it. Why would there be a keyword  error 28 do you know ?

Comment: You may want to check for a `ValueError` instead of a `KeyError`, as that is what is raised if the value is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` object feels perfect for this.

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter                                                                                                                                      

In [2]: array_2 = ['one' , "two" , "one", "three", "four"]                                                                                                                   

In [3]: array_1 = ['one', "two"]                                                                                                                                             

In [4]: a2 = Counter(array_2)                                                                                                                                                

In [5]: a1 = Counter(array_1)                                                                                                                                                

In [6]: a2 - a1                                                                                                                                                              
Out[6]: Counter({'one': 1, 'three': 1, 'four': 1})
```

If you want a list, you can flatten the `Counter` using:

```
In [7]: list((a2-a1).elements())                                                                                                                                             
Out[7]: ['one', 'three', 'four']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `map` function in combination with a `lambda` would solve your task:

```py
map(lambda x: array_2.remove(x) if x in array_2 else None, array_1)
```

This would change the `array_2` directly and the result would be:

```py
print(array_2)
# ['one', 'three', 'four']
```

Comment: @sentence Yes. The result mentioned is from the output of executed code.

Comment: This would fail if `array_1` contains an element that is not present in `array_2`.

Comment: @1313e Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the code to consider that.